# Oracle hard sql based on dates

Tags: sql, oracle, fetch

I would like to know how I can retrieve data from a database so I would have two columns. This is an example of what I would like to accomplish:

```
EMPLOYEE_Total | YEAR_HIRED
----------------------------
5                  1995
```

(number of employees hired on a particular year)

Unfortunately now I've got some troubles getting only one row per year as 
a result.

[image]

This is my query. Can you please help me? Thx.!

```
 SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) AS EMPLOYEE_TOTAL, TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'YYYY') AS YEAR_HIRED 
 FROM EMPLOYEES
 WHERE hire_date 
 BETWEEN '01-JAN-1995' AND '31-DEC-1998'
 GROUP BY HIRE_DATE
 ORDER BY HIRE_DATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example on existing Oracle table - tested:

```
SELECT count(*), to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY') hiredate 
  FROM scott.emp
 WHERE hiredate BETWEEN '01-JAN-1980' AND '01-JAN-1983'
GROUP BY to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY')
/
```

Output: ORA-01481: invalid number format model

This will work and give the same result with any of order by:

```
SELECT count(*), to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY') hiredate 
  FROM scott.emp
 WHERE hiredate BETWEEN '01-JAN-1980' AND '01-JAN-1983'
GROUP BY to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY')
--ORDER BY to_date(hiredate, 'YYYY')
-- ORDER BY hiredate
 ORDER BY 2
/

COUNT(*)    HIREDATE
-----------------------
1          1980
10         1981
1          1982
```

Comment: . . Ironically, the first form worked in SQL Fiddle for me as you have written it.  However, that is not the form I have in my answer.  I have the year being `YEAR_HIRED` -- then there is no confusion as to which variable is being used in the `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your `group by` and `order by`:

```
 SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) AS EMPLOYEE_TOTAL, TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'YYYY') AS YEAR_HIRED 
 FROM EMPLOYEES
 WHERE hire_date 
 BETWEEN '01-JAN-1995' AND '31-DEC-1998'
 GROUP BY to_char(HIRE_DATE, 'YYYY')
 ORDER BY to_char(HIRE_DATE, 'YYYY')
```

Art, the following works:

```
with emp as (select sysdate - 31*365 as hiredate from dual)
SELECT count(*), to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY') hiredate 
  FROM emp
 WHERE hiredate BETWEEN '01-JAN-1980' AND '01-JAN-1983'
GROUP BY to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY')
```

You can check it out on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8033).

Comment: @@Gordon - ORDER BY to_date(hire_date, 'YYYY') or hire_date or ORDER BY 2. Otherwise ORA-01481: invalid number format model

Comment: @Art . . . I have no idea what you are trying to say.  `hire_date` is presumably a date, and one way to get the year is `to_char(hire_date, 'yyyy')`.  I would never use `to_date()` for this.  I must admit, though, that I might use `extract(year from hiredate)` in the spirit of preferring standard SQL.

Comment: @Art . . . I tested the version on SQL Fiddle, and it works there.  I'm actually a bit surprised, that it works regardless of the name in the `select` -- whether it is called HireDate or YearHired (other SQL engines might reject the first form).

Comment: @Gordon - this is very minor thing anyway. I'm not and was not trying to be mean at all. I copied your query to TOAD w/out WITH clause and get the same error as in my example. Order by 2 or Order by hiredate w/out any formatting, which is the same thing and more readable works as expected.

Comment: @Art . . . It is interesting that it fails in Toad but works in SQL Fiddle.  Your version with ordering by "2" is also fine.

Comment: @@Gordon - I think I figured out the problem. I used the same alias as column name. Using different name for alias of hiredate works perfectly. Shame on me... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current query is very close to what you actually want.  You will want to alter your `GROUP BY` to use the `TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'YYYY')`, this causes the `grouping to be by year instead of the`hire_date` which has the month, year, etc:

```
SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) AS EMPLOYEE_TOTAL, 
  TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'YYYY') AS YEAR_HIRED 
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE hire_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-1995' AND '31-DEC-1998'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY YEAR_HIRED
```